# Elements of a group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation

> Consider the following presentation for $A_4$ $$< p, q\, |\, p^2 = (pq)^3 = q^3 =e>$$ There exist eight elements of order $3$ in this group. Deduce these elements by writing them as products of $p$ and $q$.

Attempt:

The eight elements I found were $qpq,\, pqp,\, pqpq, \,q^2, \,qp,\, pq^2,\, pq,\, q$.  Is that correct?
If I take $p = (14)(23)$ and $q = (234)$ then I can generate all $3$-cycles in $A_4$.

In particular, if I take $qp = (234)(14)(23) = (412)$ then this means $(qp)^3 = e$ since $qp$ is a $3$-cycle. However, using just the symbolic notation, I have that $(qp)^3 = q^3p^3 = p^3 = (p^2)p = e \cdot p = p \neq e$.   Why is this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in assuming $(qp)^3 = q^3p^3$. However, we can only say

$$(qp)^3 = qpqpqp$$

$(qp)^3= q^3p^3\;$ ONLY if $p$ and $q$ commute, and they do not here.

Comment: Ofcourse, thanks.  Is there any way to verify that $qp$ has order $3$ then?

Comment: You're welcome. Why not simply compute $(qp)^3?$ After all, you have both $p$ and $q$.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ represented as cycles was something I used to check that my eight products were in fact elements of order 3. I verified that $qp$ has order 3 in the OP, but I was wondering if there was a way symbolically.

Comment: @CAF $(qp)^3 = qpqpqp = q(pq)^{-1}p = qq^{-1}p^{-1}p = e$.

Comment: Why is $pqpq = (pq)^{-1}$?

Comment: Because $pqpq = (pq)^2 = (pq)^{-1}$

Comment: I don't see how $(pq)^2 = (pq)^{-1}$ Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's sort of cheating, actually, because that is true provided $pq$ is of order three, which you found to be the case, but it's also what you're trying to prove. Sorry if that's not of any help.

Comment: Yes, that helps. $pq$ is given to be of order $3$ by the question. I'll try and work the rest out. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Just to illustrate that indeed $A_4$ is not abelian, can I say that, e.g $(142)$ and $(132)$ are elements of $A_4$ (and I think it is also correct to say they are elements for all $A_n$ for at least $n=4$, i.e just send everything else to itself, yes?) and show that $(142)(132) \neq (132)(142)$.

Comment: Sure you can do just that.

Comment: Many thanks.  One last question: I managed to prove that all of the elements I showed were of order $3$.  However, I can only show that $(bab)$ is of order $3$ by using the fact that $(ab^2)$ is of order $3$ and I can only prove that $(ab^2)$ is of order $3$ by assuming that $bab$ is of order $3$! Can I show one of them is of order $3$ without assuming the other?

Comment: It's okay, I worked it out.  I can simultaneously use the fact that $ba$ and $b$ are of order $3$.